# How can I implement 2 different output for same class with JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

I want to know, how can I have 2 different serialisation with the same class when I use JAXB

I have one class Human, with a name and an age.
I need: on one REST URL to retrieve age of this person, and on a second one we can retrieve only the name of this person.
How can I implement this ?

```java
public class Human{

 private String name;
 private int age;

 public int getAge(){ return age;}
 public String getName() { return name;}
 public void setAge(int age){ this.age = age;}
 public void setName(String name) { this.name = name;}

}
```

Comment: Can you also add the code part where you are responding the REST call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one serialisation of this class. It will be a POJO of `Human`.
Then for each endpoint you will return something like this:

```
String name = human.getName();

    return Response
      .status(Response.Status.OK)
      .entity(name)
      .build();
```

For that, the endpoint method must return a `Response`, like:
`public Response getOkResponse() {`

But it would help to see your code for your endpoint.

Comment: i'm actually just inform about this, i havent a real project for send an exemple. But your response help me well. Thanks you :)